# Has anyone used android’s default FaceID authentication functionality in their android application?

Tags: android, react-native, android-10.0

Has anyone used android’s default FaceID authentication functionality in their own android application? I have gone through documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth).

I am testing this feature in Redmi 9 i.e Android Q(10). Redmi 9 have FACE verification working. When i call `hasSystemFeature()` i get `false`. And because of this faceID popup doesnot get open.

```
PackageManager pm = reactContext.getPackageManager();
pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FACE)
```

Any tip would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this)
when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate()) {
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS ->
        Log.d("MY_APP_TAG", "App can authenticate using biometrics.")
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE ->
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "No biometric features available on this device.")
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE ->
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "Biometric features are currently unavailable.")
    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED ->
        Log.e("MY_APP_TAG", "The user hasn't associated " +
        "any biometric credentials with their account.")
}
```

Please take a look to the example at https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#kotlin
Instead of the packagemanager use this to tedermine if there is biometrical hardware available and set by the user.

After that use the next code snippet from the tutorial to show the dialog with:

```
     ...

     promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
        .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
        .setNegativeButtonText("Use account password")
        .build()
     ...
```

Comment: I have followed exactly the same guide already. It always returns no fingerprints enrolled. I don't want fingerprint verification. I want faceID. to debug more I have used hasSystemFeature function